# is there such a thing as a 64bit int in c++?

Tags: c++, 64-bit

Is there a real platform/compiler combo that defines `int` as 64 bits? Or is this just used to scare new programmers like myself into using `int32_t` where size matters (e.g. saving to a file) in order to make it "portable"?

Comment: There are still systems where ints are 16 bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There absolutely are such systems. There may be more in the future (or there may not). And do you want to take a bet on what `int` will be on a possible 128-bit architecture?

Wikipedia has an incomplete-but-useful rundown: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in c99 `long long` is usually 64 bit. gcc and microsoft both use this convention.

http://jk-technology.com/c/inttypes.html#long_long

Answer (score 0):

I know that under SGI 64-bit IRIX, long ago, the `long` type declared an 64-bit integer, unless you passed the `-n32` flag and got 32-bit code instead. Sun's solution was to make up a `long long` type which was 64 bits and leave `long` as 32 bits. The old Apple Macintosh OS treated `int` as 16 bits. Rambling on, I can point out that `char` is 16 bits on several TI DSPs.

With the exception of the `long long` solution (since it changed the syntax of the language at the time), all of these were legal under the C standard. So, yeah, the rationale behind `<stdint.h>` is *not* just a scare story. It's happened.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are compilers that have 64 bit `ints`.

An `int` is typically the size of the natural word size for your architecture (i.e. a 64 bit system has 64 bit `ints`, a 16 bit system has 16 bit `ints`, etc).

And you shouldn't use `int32_t` unless you know the variable requires 32bits, such as for a network protocol, binary file format, or hardware register. If you use an `int32_t` on a 64 bit machine where it isn't necessary, then you may be introducing a performance issue for no reason. Since an `int` is the natural word size, it tends to also be the most efficient datatype. This is especially true on RISC architectures.

Comment: Wrong. Both MSVC and GCC on 64bit platforms treat `int` as 32 bits.

Comment: `int` is typically not 64-bit, but 32-bit on the x64 platform. `long long` is typically 64-bit.

Comment: There are other 64 bit architectures than Intel/AMD.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be portable you might want to store 64 bit values in a long long.